# $ gem update --system > Unable to require openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, openssl

Ruby version:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
```

When I try to:

```
$ gem update --system
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

OpenSSL is already installed:

```
$ brew install OpenSSL
Warning: openssl-1.0.1j already installed
```

Should I "rebuild ruby"? What is the best way?